# Add items to drop down list only if the first letter of the string is between A and K

Tags: c#

I have a drop down list that needs to show content that has been put into a datatable using the `SqlHelper.FillDataTable`. I use a for each statement to put each value into a list item and then add that item to the drop down list values. I would like to add this item to the drop down list only if the first letter of the name(these are names from a database) is between A and K. The current if statement I wrote results in no values being put into the drop down list. Here is the current code:

```
ListItem NewItem = new ListItem();
NewItem.Text = dr_UsersToShow["ViewValue"].ToString();
NewItem.Value = dr_UsersToShow["DataValue"].ToString();
string str = Convert.ToString(NewItem.Text[0]);
if (String.Compare("str", "A", true) >= 0 && String.Compare("str", "K", true) <= 0)
{
    this.dlNewUserList.Items.Add(NewItem);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing the literal "str" to "A" and "K". You want to compare the *string* `str` to "A" and "K". Simply remove the quotes from "str".

Change this

```
if (String.Compare("str", "A", true) >= 0 && String.Compare("str", "K", true) <= 0)
```

to this

```
if (String.Compare(str, "A", true) >= 0 && String.Compare(str, "K", true) <= 0)
```

Comment: I always overlook something like that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the quotes from "str", here you are comparing the string "str" which is not what you want I'm sure. You want to compare whatever is contained in your string variable str.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the if condition to be:

```
if (str[0] >= 'A' && str[0] <= 'K')
```

I think that would be more efficient than using the compare method.  To make it a little more readable (although not really necessary) you could go one step farther and do:

```
var firstChar = str[0];
if (firstChar >= 'A' && firstChar <= 'K')
```

I see as I reread the original question you're passing `true` to the Compare function to ignore case, so what you'd really want, then, is this:

```
var firstChar = str[0].toUpper();
if (firstChar >= 'A' && firstChar <= 'K')
```